# simple thread management within python classes

Tags: python, multithreading, class

Im trying to write a module for Python that prints out text for my program and displays a progress bar while i do something in the background. Im using the 'threading' module currently but open to suggestions if something else will make it easier.

what i want to know is two fold, ***how should i call this class elegantly and how should i stop these threads im creating?***

this is what im currently doing:

```
tmp1 = textprint("hello this is text")
tmp1.start()
# do something
tmp1.stop()
```

these are the options ive considered and [looked](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) into so far:

- using thread.name to find the name of the thread or having the thread
  return a name to kill afterwards. OR passing a number for similar
  thread identification afterwards. (a bit cumbersome and not my
  favourite solution.)

  sending a thread.event ? - from reading the docs i see an event can
  be sent, perhaps that can be used to stop it?

  or a [with](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement but im unclear how to use it in this context, plus i find most of the python docs extremely confusing and not written for me at all.

what i would *like* to do is something like this:

`echo('hello')` (prints progress bar etc)
- and then when i want to stop it `echo.stop()`

the obv. problem there though is that the stop function doesnt know which thread it is trying to stop.

Here is a skeleton of what im trying to do:

```
import time
import string
import threading

class print_text(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,arg=None):
        super(print_text,self).__init__()
        self._stop = False
        self.arg=arg

    def run (self):
        # start thread for text
        print self.txt
        while not self._stop:
                print "rude words"

    def echo (self,txt):
        self.txt=txt
        self.start()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop == True

    def __enter__(self):
        print "woo"
        return thing

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        return isinstance(value, TypeError)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print_text.start.echo('this is text') # dunt werk

    with print_text.echo('this is text'):
           time.sleep(3)

    print "done"
```

and then call it like so:

```
echo('this is text')
```

i also guess to do this i would have to

```
import echo from print_text
```

the WITH way of doing things suggests putting an `__enter__` and `__exit__` bit in. i tried them and they didnt work and also, i didnt know what i was doing, really appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You were very close to having working code.  There just needed to be a few minor fixups:

- *print_text* is a class.  It should be instantiated with `print_text()`
- The *start* method returns an instance of *print_text*, you need to save that
   in order to call *stop* and *echo* on it:  `t = print_text()`
- The *enter* method needs to return *self* instead of *thing*.
- The *exit* method should either set *_stop* or call *stop()*.
- The *echo* method should return *self* so that it can be used with the with-statement.

Here is some working code that includes those minor edits:

```
import time
import string
import threading

class print_text(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        super(print_text,self).__init__()
        self._stop = False
        self.arg=arg

    def run (self):
        # start thread for text
        print self.txt
        while not self._stop:
                print "rude words"

    def echo (self, txt):
        self.txt=txt
        self.start()
        return self

    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop == True

    def __enter__(self):
        print "woo"
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._stop = True
        return isinstance(value, TypeError)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = print_text()
    t.echo('this is text')
    time.sleep(3)
    t.stop()

    with print_text().echo('this is text'):
        time.sleep(3)

    print "done"
```

Comment: so if i import the print_text module i can then just go echo('blah') ? i dont want that print.text() in front of it and i dont really want to instantiate the class, i want it to do it itself when i call echo()

Comment: Add an *echo* function to create and run the class.  ``def echo(text, duration=3): with print_text.echo(text): time.sleep(duration)``.

Comment: what so that echo function doesnt sit *inside* the class ?

Comment: If you want to call *echo()* without instantiating the class, then yes it does need to sit outside the class.  I've fixed the code posted in your original question.  Now, it's time for you to pick-up and experiment for yourself -- it's really the only way to learn.

Comment: @funk Happy to help.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to stop a thread in Python is to politely ask it to stop. The best way to pass new data to a thread is with the `Queue` module.

Both are used in [the code in this post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/18/code-sample-socket-client-thread-in-python/), which demonstrates socket communication from a Python thread but is otherwise relevant to your question. If you read the code carefully you'll notice:

1. Using `threading.Event()` which is set by a method call from outside, and which the thread periodically checks to know if it was asked to die.
2. Using `Queue.Queue()` for both passing commands to the thread and receiving responses from it.

Comment: thanks dude, so you dont think a WITH statement is a decent solution then ? i dont have to worry too much about sending stuff to it as its just a simple text print.

Comment: @funk: I didn't examine it too closely. Conceivably, some concoction using `with` can work, depends on the situation. You did forget to use an `event` though - it's preferred over a simple attribute.

Comment: heh, i dont even know what attribute means in this context and ive never used event. thanks for your help.

Comment: @funk: attributes are "object member variables". in your code `_stop` is an attribute. Using an event can save you from running the inefficient busy loop `while not self._stop`

Answer (score 0):

A thread name is useful if you could potentially have multiple subthreads running the same target at once and want to ensure that all of them are stopped.  It seems like a useful generalization and doesn't seem too cumbersome to me, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder :-).  The following:

- starts a subthread to print a message and start a progressbar
- stops the subthread using a name given when it was started.

It is much simpler code.  Does it do what you want?

```
import time, threading

class print_text:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def progress(self):
        while not self._stop:       # Update progress bar
            print(".", sep="", end="")
            time.sleep(.5)

    def echo(self, arg="Default"):  # Print message and start progress bar
        print(arg)
        self._stop = False
        threading.Thread(target=self.progress, name="_prog_").start()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True
        for t in threading.enumerate():
            if t.name == "_prog_":
                t.join()

tmp1 = print_text()
tmp1.echo("hello this is text")
time.sleep(10)
tmp1.stop()
print("Done")
```

Comment: oh thanks, never knew you could do that, im not sure if its what i want, ill hack about and post back. thanks a lot.

Comment: no it doesnt i need more than one function, in actual fact i only need one thread, and to keep passing stuff to it.